# Jquery add time to date field

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, datetime-format

I am  getting date from datepicker

```
$("#dt").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'MM dd yy' });
```

now, I want to add default time 8:00:00 AM to the date.

var newdt =???

but not sure how, reason I didn't add time in the dateFormat is because I dont want to show the time on the UI.

also how do I disable user from entering text in the textbox? I want to allow the user to modify the date only using datepicker.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable entering text:

```
function C_buttonNeutral(element) {
    element.onclick =           function() { return false; };
    element.onmousedown =       function() { return false; };
    element.onselectstart =     function() { return false; };
}
C_button_neutral(document.getElementById('dt'));
```

to add the time:

```
document.getElementById('dt').innerHTML += ' 8:00:00 AM';
```

Edit because of comment:

```
function changeTime(element, newTime) {
    // A time like this " 8:00:00 AM" has to whitespaces.
    element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.substring(0, element.innerHTML.lastIndexOf(' '));
    element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.substring(0, element.innerHTML.lastIndexOf(' '));

    // The new time is added
    element.innerHTML += ' ' + newTime;
}

//Example:
changeTime(document.getElementById('dt'), '10:00:00 AM');
```

Comment: thx, so by default it is 8:00:00 AM and If I need later to add more time to the default time, how would I do it?